# How to get items are not in a collection in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

In my Laravel 6.x project I have `Product` model, `Warehouse` and `WarehouseProduct` models.

In the Product I store the base information of my products. In the WarehouseProduct I store the stock amount informations about products in warehouse. Of course I have many warehouses with many products.

My `Product` looks like this:

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'item_number',
        // ...
    ];
}
```

The `Warehouse` looks like this:

```php
class Warehouse extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'address',
        // ...
    ];

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany(WarehouseProduct::class);
    }

    public function missingProduct() {
        // here I need to return a Product collection which are not in this Warehouse or the
        // stored amount is 0
    }
}
```

Finally the `WarehouseProduct` looks like this:

```php
class WarehouseProduct extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'warehouse_id',
        'amount',
        // ...
    ];

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
    }

    public function warehouse() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Warehouse::class, 'warehouse_id');
    }
```

How can I get a `Product` collection which are not stored in a `Warehouse` or the amount is `0`?

Comment: Do you mean one specific Warehouse instance or any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
use App\Product;

public function missingProduct() {
    $excludedProducts = $this->products()->where('amount', '>', 0)->pluck('id');

    return Product::whereNotIn('id', $excludedProducts)->get();
}
```

Based on @KarolSobański's solution, when you add a `warehouse_products` relation to your product model:

```
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

public function missingProduct() {
    return Product::whereDoesntHave('warehouse_products', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('warehouse_id', $this->id);
    })->orWhereHas('warehouse_products', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('warehouse_id', $this->id);
        $query->where('amount', 0);
    })->get();
}
```

Comment: This actually is not a good solution - you make two database requests instead of one. You should use relations in your query to avoid such situation.

Comment: @KarolSobański I could not come up with a solution that uses the normal relationships laravel provides, so I don't think two queries are bad in this case, but could you add a solution that uses normal relationships, would be interesting to see.

Comment: added answer. At least one of proposed solutions should work

Comment: Thanks, first code is works fine, the second one not.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer might be similar to this:

```
Product::doesntHave('warehouse_products')
       ->orWhereHas('warehouse_products', function (Builder $query) {
           $query->where('amount', '=', 0)
       })->get();
```

Although I am not sure if the above works.

But the following longer query certainly resolves the issue:

```
Product::where(function ($query) {
    $query->doesntHave('warehouse_products');
})->orWhere(function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('warehouse_products', function (Builder $query) {
       $query->where('amount', '=', 0);
    });
})->get();
```